# Java WSDL2Java Axis2 Generated Content Errors

Tags: java, log4j, wsdl2java

I am using the `WSDL2Java` command line tool to generate an interface to a web-service and am experience in several errors. The script shows the following warning:

```
    log4j: WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaltOMMetaFactoryLocator).
    log4j: WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

According to my research this is because the script cannot find the log4j.properties file and is not critical, but I would like to resolve it to have a greater understanding of what is happening.

**How would you resolve this warning?**

The reference I am working from is this [URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979(v=crm.5).aspx)

Comment: "cannot find the log4j.properties file" maybe add this file?

Comment: Hello I did try adding the log4j.properties file.

I am wondering if perhaps it is a pathing issue?

Do you have any idea where it should be included?

I previously tried adding it to the root directory for the project.

Comment: No, not currently.

I could try it out? Any suggestions?